# Google maps is showing my current location in the wrong place. How I correct this?

Tags: windows, google-maps, location

When I open Google Maps and click on the location icon, right now it shows my location as Paris, France.  I am at 2405 Kent Street, Bryan, TX 77802.  It previously had me located in Toronto, Canada ; and Buenos Aires, Argentina, and Ethiopia.
I am using a Dell Inspiron 3670 with Windows 11.
Google Chrome is listed as a Default app.
I have tried setting my default location as 2405 Kent St, Bryan TS, 77802.  It shows on their map, but I get the following response: "Try another location.  We can't tell what you meant by "2405 Kent St, Bryan, TX 77802", even though that popped up after partially completing it.
I updated Chrome and Windows 11.

I have contacted MS support yesterday, and he tried several different things to correct this, and nothing worked.
I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it; nothing changed.
On Google Maps, I click on the location Icon, and select update, it puts me in Paris adjacent to the Cathedral of Notre Dame.
I click on Learn More - select computer, but it doesn't give any guidance on what to do if Google Maps is giving the wrong location.  It addresses Give Maps location permission.  I tried to give Chrome and Maps access to location; neither is listed in the Windows 11 settings-Privacy & Security - Location permission; I can't figure out how to give them access - they are not listed in the apps under location, and I can't figure out how to add them - nor could MS support.  Location services is set to on.
I went to Give Maps location permission in your browser.  The location icon is blue, but it is currently putting me in Paris France.
Bing maps shows my location in Bryan, TX a half block from my true location.
What do I do?

I just wrote all of that.

Comment: Chrome on windows tends to just use the location information registered to your public IP address, which is why it changes if you use a VPN for example. That is usually updated by your internet provider > some central registry like ARIN > Google maps. Usually you just have to wait for google to update on their end